# How to retrieve inbound/outbound network traffic value from "Measure-VM" command of Hyper-V?

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I want to monitor the internet traffic from a Hyper-V Android VM.

By running `Measure-VM Android` I can retrieve statics from the VM including network traffic

```
VMName  AvgCPU(MHz) AvgRAM(M) MaxRAM(M) MinRAM(M) TotalDisk(M) NetworkInbound(M) NetworkOutbound(M)
------  ----------- --------- --------- --------- ------------ ----------------- ------------------
Android 5007        1280      1536      1280      16384        279               6
```

I can select most of the statics. Like running `(Measure-VM Android).AvgCPU` will return 5007. However the command `(Measure-VM Android).NetworkInbound` and `(Measure-VM Android).NetworkOutbound` won't return any value. What command shall I run instead to retrieve the value properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're encountering is that
[Measure-VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/measure-vm?view=windowsserver2022-ps)
only returns a property called `NetworkMeteredTrafficReport`.
The `NetworkInbound` property does not exist and seems to be computed
from the `NetworkMeteredTrafficReport` object.

The `NetworkMeteredTrafficReport` object looks like this :

[image]

See the article
[Hyper-V VM Resource Metering via PowerShell](https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2012/12/windows-server-2012-hyper-v-vm-resource-metering-via-powershell/)
for details, but you may measure Network from or to a specific
network by using VM Network Adapter ACLs.

With ACLs, you can meter network traffic for a particular subnet
or IP address. For example :

```
Add-VMNetworkAdapterAcl -VMName SQL2012 -Action Meter -RemoteIPAddress 10.10.0.0/16 -Direction Outbound
```